# How to clean all commits from remote github repo

Tags: git, github

I had by mistake pushed hundreds of commits from my local repo to a newly created github repo.
How can I clean/remove all these commits on the remote repo so that github repo is clean as it was in the start? I would like also to lose history on those actions.
I would like to do that without affecting my local repo.

I cannot delete the branch as it is the github master branch.

Comment: If you're looking to completely reset the history, why not just delete the repo and recreate it?

Comment: If it's a new repo, you could always just delete it and push again with the proper commits.

Comment: well, yes. deleting it and recreating it is how I ended up. I just thought there is some smarter git way to clean it up.

Comment: @martin sometimes simpler is better than smarter:)

Answer (score 11):

You could:

```
- git clone <your github repo>
- git reset --hard <an_older_commit> (where you didn't have those huge files)
- git push --force origin master
```

That way:

- Your initial *local* repo isn't affected (and you can fix it in order to not push again those files)
- your remote (GitHub) repo doesn't see anymore those commits with the huge files in it.
- GitHub will run a `git gc` on its side periodically, cleaning completely the unreferenced files.

---

However the [OP Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865128/martin) mentions:

> how can I do `reset --hard` to the position before the first commit ever?
>   i.e. I would like to get the repo empty not to rollback to a previous commit

In that case, create a new local repo, make a first small commit, and `push --force` that commit.
More generally, I always try to have a first *small* initial commit on master branch when creating a repo, in order to be able to get back to a minimal commit, or to start a new branch (for an unrelated development effort) from said minimal commit.

Comment: how can I do reset -hard to the position before the first commit ever

Comment: i.e. I would like to get the repo empty not to rollback to a previous commit

Comment: +1 for *small initial commit*. I always did a `git add . && git commit` but this variant is better!

Answer (score 2):

```
git push -f REMOTE COMMIT:BRANCH
```

For example, to force the branch `master` at the remote `origin` to have undo until the commit with the id `123456` you should do

```
git push -f origin 123456:master
```